# Multiline.pattern for xml file in filebeat

Tags: xml, logstash, multiline, filebeat

What would be the multiline pattern to print all the lines under  for the below xml in filebeat

```
<?xml-stylesheet alternate="yes" href="file://c:/drive/bin/event_log.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<EventLog SetMinutes="800" Id="8000" Process="Player.exe">
<Clock ClockId="CLk-21e21412414=4-1341341414141"/>
<Entry serial_no="0" mcycle="2132424124-4141" Thread="player" ThreadId="tester" Seconds="11231243241.354123" Severity="info" >Local player details  - Receievd metrics
player has reached 1000 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 1000 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 400 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 30 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 103 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 130 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 1000 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 3300 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 1300 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 103 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 1000 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 1000 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 400 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 30 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 103 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 130 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 1000 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 3300 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 100 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 70 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 1300 level and need to get an xp
player has reached 103 level and need to get an xp
player has reached to 733 level and need to get an xp
</Entry> 
</Eventlog>
```

My filebeat multiline config.

```
multiline.pattern: '^<Entry'
          negate: true
          match: after
```

What are typical patterns for these kind of xml files ? My pattern is printing everyline as a single message.

Comment: It's may be helpful to easily debug this kind of matchers.
You could try this https://play.golang.org/p/uAd5XHxscu

Comment: I already tried it. here is my url : https://play.golang.org/p/U1UJUpyMLRo